# How to reference a component which has been already rendered but the user hasn't interacted with it?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I am on my journey to learn React but struggling with referencing existing components.

My objective is to show both Markers and InfoWindow at the same time, once the user click in any of them.
Here the code I am using:

```
export class WhereWeFly extends Component {

    state = {
        showingInfoWindow: false,  // Hides or shows the InfoWindow
        activeMarker: {},          // Shows the active marker upon click
        selectedPlace: {},          // Shows the InfoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
        dependentRef: {}
      };

    onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
        selectedPlace: props,
        activeMarker: marker,
        showingInfoWindow: true,
        clicked: true,
        location: marker.name
    });

    onClose = props => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
        this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null,
        clicked: false
        });
    }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <div className='wherewefly' id='wherewefly'>
                <div className='wwf-title' id='wwf-title'>
                    <h1>
                        <i class='fas fa-map-marker'></i>
                        <span>Where do we fly to?</span>
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <Map
                    google={this.props.google}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    style={mapStyles}
                    initialCenter={initCenter}>
      
                    <Marker
                        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                        name={'First'}
                        position={                    
                            {
                                lat: -23.42,
                                lng: -46.47
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <Marker
                        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                        t={this.state.dependentRef}
                        name={'Second'}
                        position={                    
                            {
                                lat: -24.42,
                                lng: -47.47
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <InfoWindow
                        marker={??????????}
                        visible={true}
                    >
                        <div className='wwf-marker'>
                            <h4>
                                {'First'}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow> 
                    <InfoWindow
                        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
                        onClose={this.onClose}
                    >
                        <div className='wwf-marker'>
                            <h4>
                                {'Second'}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow> 

                </Map>
            </div>
        </>
        );
  }
}
```

How can I reference the marker here:

```
marker={??????????}
```

Should I use a combination of useRef and useState? If yes, how? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Refs should do the trick, here's how to [create and use one](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)

After you have created your have in your class component and assigned it to `Marker`, you can just pass the ref to `InfoWindow` as a prop `markerRef`, and access the current `Marker` component with `props.markerRef.current`.

If `Marker` is a function component, you'll need to change it to a `FowardRef` function component, as functions can't hold references.